# How to get the current time on a button click?

Tags: android

I know am not the first to ask this ,What I need to do is when I close the current activity by clicking on a button ,I want to show the current time .

**This will have the following validation.**

1,In the current activity I have a timepicker if I select any time any click on the save button it will show the sellected time and closing the current activity.

2,If I am not selected any time from timepicker  and On the save button click I want to show the current time .

For me the First one is working fine but the second one is always showing null.

TimePicker Time :

```
mTimePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1) {
                int hour = i % 12;
                mselectedTime = (String.format("%02d:%02d %s", hour == 0 ? 12 : hour, i1, i < 12 ? "AM" : "PM"));
            }
        });
```

code :

```
 mSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mselectedTime == "null"){
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm.ss aa");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Time Is :" + dateFormat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mselectedTime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateAlarm.this, AlarmActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out, R.anim.slide_out);
            }
        });
```

Here the second Toast is showing the time ,but First toast is always showing empty .I need to show the time as **04:50 Am/Pm format** in the first toast

Can anyone tell me where I did the mistake .

Comment: What is mSelectedTime?in time picker when you implement it, there is an override function, which shows the selected time, you should check the time in that function

Comment: You trying to comparing String with `==` which is incorrect. Try using `mSelectedTime.isEquals("null");`. Btw, why are using String comparison for checking time?

Comment: Use .isEqual() instead of ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second toast you need to reacquire the time, then add it to the toast, not the `SimpleDateFormat`. Here's the code:

```
Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm.ss aa");
String output = dateFormat.format(currentTime);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Time Is :" + output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh.mm aa");
        String dateString = dateFormat.format(new Date()).toString();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Current time :"+ dateString,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and you may have imported wrong packages use.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Calendar instance you can get current hour and minutes

```
    Calendar c;
        private int mhour;
        private int mminute;
c = Calendar.getInstance();
mhour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
mminute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

// you will get current hour and minutes of device time
```

also refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar)